# Finding dates in text using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I want to find all dates in a text if there is no word Effective before the date.
For example, I have the following line:

`FEE SCHEDULE Effective January 1, 2022 STATE OF January 7, 2022 ALASKA DISCLAIMER The January 5, 2022`

My regex should return `['January , 2022', 'January 5, 2022']`

How can I do this in Python?

My attempt:

```
>>> import re
>>> rule = '((?<!Effective\ )([A-Za-z]{3,9}\ *\d{1,2}\ *,\ *\d{4}))'
>>> text = 'FEE SCHEDULE Effective January 1, 2022 STATE OF January 7, 2022 ALASKA DISCLAIMER The January 5, 2022'
>>> re.findall(rule, text)
[('anuary 1, 2022', 'anuary 1, 2022'), ('January 7, 2022', 'January 7, 2022'), ('January 5, 2022', 'January 5, 2022')]
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post your code that generated the output from 'my attempt'.

Comment: `\b(?<!Effective\s)[A-Za-z]{3,9}\ *\d{1,2}\s*,\s*\d{4}(?!\d)` will do. See https://regex101.com/r/CHuhYw/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?<!Effective\s)[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*\d{1,2}\s*,\s*\d{4}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CHuhYw/2). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!Effective\s)`  - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `Effective` + a whitespace char immediately to the left of the current location
- `[A-Za-z]{3,9}` - three to nine ASCII letters
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit immediately on the right.